# Set up GTK+ to display GUIs in MinGW

Tags: c, gtk, cygwin, mingw

This is a university assignment to make GUI's in C - I am using windows 7

I have followed several tutorials and nothing seems to work. To give you an idea of what I have done

I have gtk, msys and minGW all installed.

I believe I have all the necessary cygwin packages (is this relevant??)

When I try to compile a C program with gtk stuff included in cygwin just to see if I have installed whatever I needed to I get

```
$ gcc base.c -o base `gtk-config --cflags --libs`

Sunny@Sunny-Brain ~
$ ./base

Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I am not sure what this mean. It seems to compile and then fails on running.

I have used https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2008-May/msg00116.html as the method of setting gtk up but it asks me to unzip and untar a pixman file which doesnt work. I downloaded gtk as a bundle and it is in my C: drive eager to make GUI's for me.

In case it helps - I have a pixman-0.26.2 and inside, a pixman-0.26.2.tar.gz - also in my C: drive.

At this point I am willing to try anything.

Comment: Using a tutorial from 2008 *might* not be the safest route. I haven't tried GTK+ in Windows in a long (long) while, but I would recommend looking for something more recent, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have installed the X11 version of GTK using Cygwin. The X11 version of GTK requires an X server to be running in order to use it. The error message is telling you that the environment variable telling GTK which X server to connect to is not set. That probably means that no X server is running.

I recommend that you install the **Windows** version of GTK (which does not require an X server and also uses a native Windows look and feel by default) and compile using that and MinGW. You shouldn't need to use Cygwin at all.

Comment: @ unwind - fair point. @sepp2k If I install a specific gtk package for windows, would I compile it using the same commands in minGW as I used in cygwin. Also, would I need to install anything else to make this work? Sorry if it looks like I am trying to get all the answers from you but this is a scenario in which I have seen all of the tutorials online and they haven't worked *SAD FACE. Cheers

Comment: @SunnyNewb You shouldn't need to compile GTK at all. It comes as a pre-compiled package. And no, if you have mingw as well as the all-in-one package from the GTK home page installed, that should be all you need.

Comment: @SunnyNewb: Just download the all-in-one bundle of GTK2 for Windows, as specified at GTK official website: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php .(search "all-in-one" in the page). There's currently no bundle for GTK3. Uninstall cygwin, you won't need it if you use MinGW+MSYS. I already have compiled apps using that setup (MinGW+MSYS+GTK2), this isn't that hard. You'll just need to put the GTK bundle in /opt, and add the bin directory that is in the bundle to your PATH environment variable. That way your system will find pkg-config, which is required to find the GTK lib and its dependencies.

Comment: @liberforce: I added mingw to the PATH. is there something special about 'opt'? the currrent directory is C:\MinGW\bin\; At the moment I have an error at compilation in the mingw32 terminal. When i try to compile gcc base.c -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` I get gcc.exe: error: base.c: No such file or directory. Does something within mingw expect my gtk (currently in C:\gtk) to be in a folder named 'opt'? cheers

Comment: No, nothing special about /opt, just that this is what is advised in the UNIX FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard). But don't mix Windows paths and UNIX-style paths. Use the `pwd` command to know the UNIX path of the current directory, and `pwd -W` to know the Windows equivalent. You can also edit /etc/fstab to configure mount points, and map Windows directories to their UNIX counterpart. That way I could handle /opt as a completely separate directory that could survice MinGW reinstallations. For your error, the current directory returned by `pwd` must be the one that contains your base.c file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I already had cygwin installed. I used mingw and msys because:

1) I am a newb

2) Being a newb I went online, found a few tutorials on setting up GTK and just naively  followed them.

If you have cygwin installed already you do not need mingw or msys. But you do need the following:

a) The appropriate cygwin packages installed:
When using the cygwin installer, do not use the default install. Either find out what packages you specifically need or install all of them and delete as appropriate if you know what you are doing.

b) In order to display GUI's, there needs to be an environmental path variable for displaying it. Set it using this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

then check it using

```
echo $display
```

it should echo -

```
:0
```

check that you can display a GUI using:

```
xclock&
```

If this displays a clock, then you are set to do some GTK tutorials.